# Error Code: 1241 MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have Error Code: 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**tabla1:**

```
idtabla1,id_connector, nombre, apellido, descripcion,date, modification_date
```

**tabla_historica:**

```
idtabla1,id_connector, nombre, apellido, descripcion,date, modification_date
```

**my query is:**

```
INSERT INTO tabla_historica (id_connector, nombre, apellido, descripcion,date) value ((SELECT id_connector, nombre, apellido, descripcion, date
        FROM    tabla1 r 
        WHERE row(r.id_connector, r.nombre, r.apellido, r.descripcion, r.date) NOT IN 
        (SELECT id_connector, nombre, apellido, descripcion, date FROM tabla_historica)));
```

Comment: A subquery can return only one column

Answer (score 1):

If your query in the question is what you try to run, you should replace **VALUE** with **VALUES**, like below:

```
INSERT INTO tabla_historica
            (id_connector,
             nosmbre,
             apellido,
             descripcion,
             DATE)
VALUES      ((SELECT id_connector,
                     nombre,
                     apellido,
                     descripcion,
                     DATE
              FROM   tabla1 r
              WHERE  ROW(r.id_connector, r.nombre, r.apellido, r.descripcion,
                     r.DATE) NOT IN
                     (SELECT
                     id_connector,
                             nombre,
                             apellido,
                             descripcion,
                             DATE
                     FROM
                             tabla_historica)))
```